# MVD axioms and properties

Tags: database, functional-dependencies

If X->->Y and X->->Z then does it imply X->->YZ ?

I tried few examples and found this to be true. I couldn't find this property or it's proof in any website.

Can someone please tell if the above property always holds true or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Union Rule holds also for Multivalued Dependencies, not only for Functional Dependencies.

I think the first proof of this rule has been given in the following paper: A Complete Axiomatization for Functional and Multivalued Dependencies in Database Relations, by C.Beeri, R.Fagin, and J.H.Howard, Proc. of 1977 ACM SIGMOD Conference ([bibliographic reference](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=509414&CFID=846750519&CFTOKEN=70492541), [pdf copy](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.62.5791&rep=rep1&type=pdf)).

The proof given in the paper is the following :

```
1. X ->-> Z            (given)
2. X ->-> XZ           (by augmentation of 1 with X)
3. X ->-> Y            (given)
4. XZ ->-> YZ          (by augmentation of 3 with Z)
5. XZ ->-> U - X - YZ  (by complementation of 4, U are all the attributes of the relation)
6. X ->-> U - X - YZ   (by transitivity of 2 and 5, since XZ and U - X - YZ are disjoint)
7. X ->-> YZ           (by complementation of 6)
```

Comment: If this is really true, then the wikipedia article about 4NF decomposition is somewhat incorrect https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_normal_form. The two dependencies given can be combined into one FD by union property and the MVD becomes trivial and thus the relation should be in 4NF. But it's not. @Renzo.

Comment: @Zephyr The wiki 4NF example T has {R} ↠ {PV} & {R} ↠ {DA}. So T = T{DA, R} join T{R, PV} & T = T{PV, R} join T{R, DA}. Those say the same thing. {R} ↠ {PV, DA} is trivial, so *every* MVD implies it. (We don't need the theorem in your question.) That doesn't mean that MVDs that imply it are trivial. Anyway, why "thus the relation should be in 4NF"? I guess you think the 2 MVDs together implying a trivial MVD means the 2 are trivial. That is just wrong & unjustified. Yet again you reason unsoundly and use strange/sloppy terms--"combined into one", "becomes". (And I guess you mean MVD not FD?)

Comment: @philipxy Wiki example has R ->->P and R ->-> D dependency. By union property, R->->PD is also true . So the relation with 3 columns (R,P,D) should be in 4NF as union of attributes in R->->PD gives us the set of entire attributes in the Relation. But according to wiki, it's not in 4NF.

Comment: I am talking about the restaurant and pizza delivery example.

Comment: @Zephyr Reread my last comment. Once again, the 2 MVDs imply the third; it happens to be trivial so they *must* imply it regardless of your title; that doesn't make the 2 trivial; they are still 2 non-trivial MVDs not out of superkeys; so 4NF is violated. *Why* do you think (wrongly) the 2 non-trivials implying a trivial MVD implies 4NF?? *All* MVDs imply the trivial MVDs--they're the ones we know must hold without looking at other MVDs or data.

Comment: @philipxy why do you need first two MVD's after union ? They are like redundant MVD's. Only one MVD R->->DP is enough.

Comment: @Zephyr You are using everyday terms that mean nothing--"need", "after", "like", "redundant", "enough". You are just writing nonsense. Use the definitions & theorems/rules you have been given. Read my comments & my answer on your latest question. Here's how you are reasoning [sic]: "a=3 and b=2 imply 1=1 (or, a > 0) but now that I know that's true i can ignore that a=3 and b=2 in ...". I have commented on other posts of yours that you are not using correct terms or definitions or theorems or reasoning soundly. (Things that *are implied* are "redundant", not things *that imply*.)